# Use the MS Graph REST API to order Tasks within a TaskList?

Tags: api, rest, microsoft-graph-api

I'm playing with sample code and looking through the documentation on the Task List part of the MS Graph 1.0 REST API, and I'm trying to figure out how one might change the order of Tasks within a TaskList.

Thank you!

Comment: See here for a similar question, including an answer to use the (old and deprecated) Outlook API for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71851210/how-to-get-and-set-custom-sorting-order-on-ms-to-do-using-graphapi

Answer (score 0):

Sorting, filtering, pagination, and so on requests that requires any data are performing typically via url params or http body data. Check "API usage" section for pagination or any create method to see how it looks like. Documentation for TaskList request does not provide currently any info about params or http body.